# git: removing changes introduced by a series of bad commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

say i have a git repo, with such commit history: A-B-C-D-E

Now, suddenly i realise, that commits B and C are completely flawed and unnecessary.
Also, say i have the complete freedom to rewrite project history (perhaps i'm working on the project alone).

I have another branch pointing to the commits B and C, so losing them is not a problem. If i ever actually need those changes, i can checkout that branch and see them.

But for the master branch, i would like to force the history to be A-D'-E', where D and E not only have a modified parents list, but also do not contain the changes that were introduced by commits B and C.

Is this possible to do? And if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git rebase -i HEAD~5`

Then, remove the unwanted commits from the list of commits

Comment: Nice! I have never used rebase -i before, but it seems to make rebasing possible for mere mortals (like myself). I thought this problem may be possible to solve by rebase, thats why i tagged it with "git-rebase", but rebasing is kinda hard to wrap your head around (at least for me). Not to mention you can easily screw up your repo history with it. But -i seems really easy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume there are 5 commits.

In which case you'll do a:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

Then you'll remove the 2 lines pertaining to commits B and C.

Finally, you'll do a:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: `rebase --continue` is only necessary if the rebase has to stop for user input, which it won't in this case unless there are conflicts applying `D` after `B` and `C` have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rebase --onto $commit_A $commit_C $commit_E
```

This says “take all the commits after C, up to and including E, and replay them on top of A”.

You can use any notation for the commits you are referring to, of course. Eg. if `master` is at E and you have a branch pointing at C, say `backup`, you can also say this:

```
git rebase --onto $commit_A backup master
```

This is even more convenient as you will be left with `HEAD` pointed at `master`, and `master` in turn pointed at the re-written E.